TERADATA query to perform sum using reference table
I have following data in the reference table:
Reference Table:

My source table= EMP:
Data is as shown below:

I need output using reference table as below.
Suppose, source value is 20 then it should give me output as:
C,E (20=sum of No. column 4+16)
Likewise, if source value is 255 then o/p should be:
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H (255= sum of no. 1+2+4+8+16+32+64+128)
Expected Output:

Can someone share the query to perform this?
TIA


A [mcve] is supposed to include sample data for all involved tables and the expected result (use properly formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Clunky, but you might convert the source integer to binary then parse/pivot out each factor

Teradata supports a bunch of Bit/Byte functions

Thank you all..
I have solved this using binary functions.
